# What is the alternative for HttpContext.Response.OutputStream to use in WebAPI's HttpResponseMessage

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

I'm writing a WebAPI for handling PDF documents. It was written in a ashx page earlier implementing IHttpHandler and getting the context using HttpContext. I'm now writing it using WebAPI. In WebAPI we have HttpResponseMessage. For HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite we have new ByteArrayContent in HttpResponseMessage. But what is the alternative for HttpContext.Response.OutputStream in WebAPI? I need to have the alternative of OutputStram in WebAPI because im passing this OutputStream as a parameter to another dll.

Code in ashx:

```
SomeReport.PdfReport rpt = new SomeReport.PdfReport(docID);
rpt.CreateReport(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you can use any stream for example `MemoryStream` but result should be wrapped into `StreamContent`.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();

    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    //write data to output stream
    //or passing it to somewhere
    outputStream.WriteByte(83);

    outputStream.Position = 0;
    response.Content = new StreamContent(outputStream);

    return response;    
}
```

If you need direct writing to output stream, please consider using `PushStreamContent`. [Example](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/)

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. It worked. I was concerned about using MemoryStream. I would try the PushStreamContent as well.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. You saved my day. I was receiving empty result and your example showed me that I was missing the row ```outputStream.Position = 0;```

Comment: Glad to help you, Luca.